# Deis paas on Google Cloud don't understand a command

Tags: google-cloud-platform, paas, deis

I'm deploying Deis Paas on Google Cloud.
In the official provisioning guide available at http://docs.deis.io/en/latest/installing_deis/install-platform/ 
there are a few commands.

I don't understand on which domain this command refers

```
deisctl config platform set domain=example.com
```

what should I put instead of "example.com"?

Answer (score 1):

Are you following these docs? http://docs.deis.io/en/latest/installing_deis/gce/#deis-on-gce

If so then the domain will be your/company domain.

Once you have this in your configs, you can create subdomains from DEIS CLI itself which can also be written in config files. This helps automating the provisioning of subdomains and if need be during scaling using dynamic provisioning.

More details:

- When you are looking at a solution which can do automatic
  deployments, that means that not only that solution will deploy an
  instance with your application code in it, but also that it will
  configure the network, proxy or configuring access to databases etc.
- One of these processes is to configure a subdomain for your application. You could be running your website on `domain.com` and
  your webapp on `web.domain.com`, while your database can be running
  on `db.domain.com`.
- This is easily configurable manually, but in most cases when you deploy a new instance, the IP for that instance is randomly selected
  from a pool of IPs. Hence its rare that you will get the same IP
  again on next deployment. NOTE: We are not talking about deploying
  app on a VM, but deploying a new VM altogether with updated
  application code.
- Similar cases arise when you want to do auto-scaling during load balancing or a alpha release which will auto-upgrade releases on all
  the instances.
- For all such cases either you can set the `CNAME` and `A Records` manually or you can let DEIS do it for you.
- In order for DEIS (or similar solutions) to do it, you need to verify your domain name (or at-least configure). Once this domain
  name is in global configurations, everytime you launch a newer
  version of your web-app, DEIS can put it in a instance and point it
  at `v1-web.domain.com`.
- Once its verified that deployment was successful and its serving, it can now be auto-upgraded to `web.domain.com`. All this happening based on the rules that you specify in configurations of you application.

Hope this is enough. If not you should read more about how Google App-Engine works, or rather give it a try.

Comment: Yes, those are the docs I'm following.
I've thought that I was configuring a new domain on Google cloud and that I was installing Deis on that domain.
I've thought also that I was deploying apps on subdomains of this domain but from your answer I deduce I'm a little bit confused.
 Could you please synthetize me this domain thing?

Comment: Hey @chriscris: I have added more details to the answer. let me know if it suffices.